# Socket.io и правильный disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, сокет, socket.io

Я столкнулся с ситуацией, когда мне нужно оставлять соединение открытым если юзер нажал F5 в браузере, `disconnect` должен срабатывать только если юзер например закрыл вкладку или браузер. Это нужно, например в том случае, если человек заходит на сайт, и при коннекте сокета я уведомляю всех кто в онлайне о том что такой-то юзер зашел на сайт. В стандартной ситуации, при каждом обновлении страницы будет срабатывать событие `connection`, и будет уведомлять каждый раз всех кто в онлайне.

Как решить такую задачу?

P.S.
Как вариант можно рассмотреть [этот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260170/handle-browser-reload-socket-io).

Но, мне не очень нравится такой подход, хотя и можно ставить таймер на `disconnect`, а при коннекте проверять в массиве с авторизованными клиентами, есть ли с таким sessid, и если есть - то не делать действия те что в `connection`.

Но, я почему-то верю, что есть более интересные варианты решения задачи. Прошу местных гуру отписаться по этому поводу)

Comment: Коннект по любому порвется. потому что браузер при перезагрузке страницы выгружает все скрипты и потом запускает их по новой. И коннект может порваться просто по сетевым проблемам, а не только по F5 и почти тут же переконнектится, если клиентская часть конечно это делает. Таймаут мне кажется оптимальным решением

Comment: Без таймера вам не обойтись по одной простой причине: вам нужно иметь некоторый промежуток времени, когда заново вошедший пользователь не будет считаться уходившим. Причем событие реального отключения пользователя должно происходить только **после** окончания этого временного промежутка

Comment: При F5 disconnect может не произойти, потому что браузеры "для ускорения" держат сокеты keep alive (кешируют), даже если удаленный сервер не выставил keep. Приходится посылать код потока обработчиком ухода со страницы, или ставить таймер на страницу (если остановили скачивание)

Comment: А чем сессии не подходят? Хоть 100 раз нажмет F5 данные в сессии все равно будут.

Comment: Вы, похоже, прочитали только пол вопроса. После перезагрузок сессия-то останется, но при реальном уходе человека из чата, его все равно как-то нужно прибивать. И в этом случае, сессии совсем не являются решением проблемы

Answer (score 2):

1. Фронт каждые Х секунд шлёт на сервер пинг, что он онлайн. Онлайн проверяется на фронте (движение мышкой в окне и т.д.)
2. Каждая открытая вкладка шлёт такой пинг.
3. Если пинг ни от куда не приходил ХХ секунд - делаешь пользователя оффлайн.
4. Как только пользователь сделает какое-либо действие на фронте, то придёт пинг на сервер и ты разошлёшь всем сообщения, что пользователь снова онлайн.